Weird New Hampshire Blue Law About Lingerie Near The Airport?
Friend of mine asked me to confirm and/or expound on the history and rationale behind the 'Kidderville, New Hampshire' entry in this infographic:

Those without images, the entry reads:

No hanging lingerie on a clothesline near the airport.

I'd never heard of this.  After doing some digging, apparently the claim comes from the November 1987 issue of Private Pilot magazine.
After doing some more digging, I've come to the conclusion that the airport in question must be Gifford Field (4C4) as it's the only airport remotely close aside from Errol (KERR) which would certainly have been called Errol, NH instead of Kidderville.  (Kidderville, itself is a tiny village and part of Colebrook... that they said Kidderville is probably indicative of something, but I can't get my hands on the villages municipal code.)
Given the highly specific nature of the ordinance, there's almost certainly a story here and on my friend's behalf I'm asking for that story.

Probably a fascinating story, but near an airport or not, I don't think laws about what can't be hung on clotheslines is an Aviation question.

@RalphJ I may end up agreeing, but to my mind the story has to involve some kind of incident on the field.

@mins He got it off Twitter. The tweet doesn't give a source.

I'm in touch, now, with the Kidderville historical society. Assuming they provide the source, and it's on-topic for aviation, I'll get an answer here sooner or later. Otherwise I'll delete the question.

Reportedly, the Nov 1987 issue of Private Pilot specified 'at the airport' but yeah, it's a weird one.

Maybe hanging clothes being confused for a windsock?  I will say that these 'weird law' listicles often misstate the law by giving a specific example that does fall under the rule but is not the full and total extent of the law. Like  it'll say "A law in XYZ makes it illegal to carry a sign on a sidewalk on sunday" or some such thing, and when you hunt down the actual law it's an ordinance about causing an obstruction on a public sidewalk and has nothing to do with signs in specific or sundays in specific. (That's one reason it's often so difficult to track down the real law!)

@WilliamWalkerIII do you have a link to the tweet? I assume the image came from there?

@300D7309EF17 https://twitter.com/jetcitystar/status/422595354102489088

looks like the actual source was probably io9 in 2013. there are some references to sources in their article. The Kidderville/Lingerie question was asked on skeptics.se almost ten years ago, unanswered.

further, the "Private Pilot Nov 1987" reference is in a Montana Department of Transportation newsletter in 2004.

Having spoken with a current and former Town Clerk for the involved municipality, I am unable to substantiate this claim.  I'll leave this up for a bit longer since it was upvoted enough to be net positive, but I'm not going to actively pursue this matter further and if folks don't want it closed I'll eventually post an answer with where the trail went cold.

@DarthPseudonym Or somebody's laundry kept blowing away and causing a FOD problem

The November 1987 issue of Private Pilot that this seems to be sourced from is currently available on eBay for pretty cheap if you want to track this one step further.

@RalphJ, I disagree, the fact that it mentions 'near the airport' indicates that there might be an aviation-related reason.

Given discussion, I'm adding the answer so the pair can be evaluated together.

I don't think this has anything to do with aviation, regardless of where it was originally stated. Also, I do not think the law is actually enforced, if it even exists. Somebody should VtC as off-topic.

Most likely no such ordinance existed, if it did it was an airfield policy rather than a local law.
The only likely candidate 'airport' this could be in reference to would be 4C4, Gifford Field - a privately owned, public-use turf strip in Colebrook, 7 miles from Kidderville. While I've not found an official founding date for the airfield, evidence below leads me to conclude that it opened to the public in 1963.
According to the current (as of August 2024) town clerk and the former town clerk before her (spoke to both via email), no such law or ordinance passed in Colebrook (the legal municipality of which Kidderville, NH is part) since 1950. While not 100% definitive, because aviation was a thing before the 1950s, but after review of the historical record I'm confident the claim cannot be further substantiated.
In correspondence one of the clerks opined that the rumored ordinance sounded like a joke of the sort told by 'Dr Gifford' after whom there is reason to believe the airfield is named. Dr. William H. Gifford is credited with being the prime mover regarding the establishment of the only hospital for miles.  Dr. Gifford would also write a history of the town titled "Colebrook: A Place Up Back Of New Hampshire." Excerpts from that book (I was unable to acquire a copy) suggest that the town's airport officially opened in 1963.
According to the November 1987 issue of Private Pilot, the rule paraphrased in the graphic was actually that no lingerie was to be hung on a clothesline at the airport without sufficient screen 'against prying eyes.'
While municipal ordinances are often written by amateur policymakers, they rarely have so informal a tone - whereas writers of pop-history texts - particularly those with a reputation for tomfoolery - make use of that sort of tone quite often.
It seems most likely, therefore, that the former town clerk of Colebrook is correct and that either Dr. Gifford made this comment in speech or it appears as part of his history of Colebrook, just on a page I couldn't recover without going to extraordinary lengths to confirm (if this changes I'll update).
The list of 'weird rules at airports' that this appeared in seems to have been solicited by editors of Private Pilot and since that issue predates the Internet verification of such rules would likely have been far costlier than the amusement value of the piece so the editors may simply have taken the submissions at face value as 'credibly sourced.'

I got my hands on the ''Private Pilot'' issue. "Looney Laws For Pilots: Leftover laws not even a lawyer could love, remain in aviation.", authored by Robert Pelton. No sourcing. "can't be hung on a clothesline at the airport... [unless] carefully hidden... by a suitable screen".
